# Get Set-Cookie in header using requests module

Tags: python, cookies

When I use PHP to get cookie, it returns:

```
session_id=abih14s7l4lgo3splta7f6bd14; cccaa78fa9e13785130119a4924db0f4=96637ae... (more)
```

But when I use Python, it returns:

```
session_id=abih14s7l4lgo3splta7f6bd14
```

... the rest of cookies is lost.

My code Python:

```
res_post = requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = {mydata})
cookies = dict(res_post.cookies.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the `requests` library. The `response.cookies` is already a dictionary, so there's no need to cast it again.

You should access the cookies on the response like so:

```
response = requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data={mydata})
print response.cookies['session_id']
```

See here for more detail: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: Thank you!

But I want to get all cookies as PHP above, not only `session_id`. Sorry for my English.

Comment: All of the cookies are right there in `request.cookies`

Comment: How I get it from `request.cookies`?

I search it in `http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/` but I don't see information about it.

Comment: Get what? `response.cookies` _is_ it. It is a dictionary which has the cookie names for keys and the cookie values for values.

Comment: _it_ is cookies. I tried `print response.cookies`, it returns: `<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session_id=mmnhc7jbapim2hpggtrupdbqo5 for www.abc.def>]>`. It isn't all.

Comment: Then the client is sending them over.