# Cookie selectively not sent with Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, fiddler

Using the `requests` module with Python 3.6 (also happens with 3.5), here's the essence of my code:

```
sess=requests.Session()
login_to_stackexchange(sess) # logs in to SE
print(sess.cookies) # see below
sess.post("chat.stackexchange.com/something",data=data) # data={"index":stuff}
```

The cookies at line 3 are:

```
<Cookie acct=t=[key here]&s=[key here] for .stackexchange.com/>
<Cookie prov=[key here] for .stackexchange.com/>
```

However when looking at the sent request using Fiddler, *only the first cookie (prov) is sent*. I need both cookies for my requests to work.

Why is requests only sending one cookie ?
How can I fix that ?

---

"Full" cookie returned by line 3:

```
<Cookie uauth=true for .chemistry.stackexchange.com/>
<Cookie acct=t=[key here]&s=[key here] for .stackexchange.com/>
<Cookie prov=[key here] for .stackexchange.com/>
<Cookie sechatusr=t=[key here] for chat.stackexchange.com/>
<Cookie anon=[key here] for openid.stackexchange.com/>
```

Comment: So why are you not using the Stack Exchange API instead? See https://api.stackexchange.com/ Then you don't have to worry about having to spoof a login.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The API does not enable interaction with chat rooms

Comment: Then at least don't re-invent the wheel: https://github.com/ByteCommander/ChatExchange6

Comment: @MartijnPieters My issue is that I had [a chatbot](https://github.com/gauthierhaas/SE_Bot) working perfectly for several months, and suddently it stopped working yesterday, and when I diagnosed the error it came from that cookie handling. I'm trying to fix it, not redo a new chatbot.

Comment: Then please show us the `Set-Cookie` headers (incoming) and `Cookie` header (outgoing) to show what the actual exchange is. On the whole, I'm inclined to trust the requests cookie handling code, as it uses the long-stable cookielib library code included in Python.

Comment: You may want to compare your login code with the project I referenced (which is used by several still-operating bots in use today), and see what the differences are in how they handle the login. Perhaps your current flow simply no longer works.

Comment: The issue souldn't be with the login, since I am able to open a websocket to the chatrooms after logging in. The issue is only with sending messages by requests to http://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/roomId/messages/new. I have checked that code before when debugging but dit not find any obvious clue.
As for the ``Set-Cookie`` and ``Cookie`` headers, I'm not sure what you mean that I haven't already added ? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113005/get-set-cookie-in-header-using-requests-module) seems to indicate that the ``Set-Cookie`` is the one I printed above

Comment: You printed what is stored in the cookie jar, but that info is not entirely complete. Various flags and expiration data are not shown, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160136/discussion-between-hippalectryon-and-martijn-pieters).